# Problem with Pulse Sensor signal

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, button

I'm making alarm with input from pulse sensor. When it detect high heart rate then it send a text message. Everything works fine when i am using potentiometer (as input) for simulating triggering SMS. I made several heart rate trigger options based on ages, so i'm using switch-case in my loop. I'm using PulseSensor Playground library and some sample skecth that came from with it, but when i put program that read beat per minute and put that value inside if statement it become doesn't work at all. Even if i put the BPM value to serial monitor it only display 0. What can i do to fix this problem? Thanks

Here is my program:

```
#define USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true     
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h>     
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>              
#include <JC_Button.h>

const int OUTPUT_TYPE = SERIAL_PLOTTER;
const int PulseSensor = A0;  
const int THRESHOLD = 550;  

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;
SoftwareSerial SIM800L(2, 3);  //(RX | TX)
const byte switchButton = 4;
int LED1 = 5;   //ages range 1
int LED2 = 6;   //ages range 2
int LED3 = 7;   //ages range 3
int greenLED  = 8;    //for normal heart rate
int yellowLED  = 9;   //for medium heart rate
int redLED = 10;      //for high heart rate

Button mybutton(switchButton);
boolean SMSsent = false;
int x = 0;

void setup(){
  mybutton.begin();
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseSensor);
  pulseSensor.setSerial(Serial);
  pulseSensor.setOutputType(OUTPUT_TYPE);
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(THRESHOLD);

  SIM800L.begin(115200);  
  Serial.println("SIM800L ready");
}

void led_for_ages_range_1(){
  digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
}
void led_for_ages_range_2(){
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED3, LOW);
}
void led_for_ages_range_3(){
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(LED3, HIGH);
}

void led_indicator_1(){
  digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(yellowLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
}
void led_indicator_2(){
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellowLED, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
}
void led_indicator_3(){
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(yellowLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
}

void range_1_indicator(){
  int BPMval = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();

  if (BPMval > 60 && BPMval < 85){
    led_indicator_1();
    SMSsent = false;
  }
  else if (BPMval > 86 && BPMval < 100){
    led_indicator_2();
    if(SMSsent == false){
      text_message_1();
      SMSsent = true;
    }
  }
  else if (BPMval > 101){
    if(SMSsent == false){
      text_message_2();
      SMSsent = true;
    }
  } 
  else {
    SMSsent = false;
  }
}

void range_2_indicator(){
  int BPMval = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();

  if (BPMval > 60 && BPMval < 75){
    led_indicator_1();
    SMSsent = false;
  }
  else if (BPMval > 76 && BPMval < 90){
    led_indicator_2();
    if(SMSsent == false){
      text_message_1();
      SMSsent = true;
    }
  }
  else if (BPMval > 91){
    if(SMSsent == false){
      text_message_2();
      SMSsent = true;
    }
  } 
  else {
    SMSsent = false;
  }
}

void range_3_indicator(){
  int BPMval = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();

  if (BPMval > 60 && BPMval < 70){
    led_indicator_1();
    SMSsent = false;
  }
  else if (BPMval > 71 && BPMval < 80){
    led_indicator_2();
    if(SMSsent == false){
      text_message_1();
      SMSsent = true;
    }
  }
  else if (BPMval > 81){
    if(SMSsent == false){
      text_message_2();
      SMSsent = true;
    }
  } 
  else {
    SMSsent = false;
  }
}

void text_message_1(){
  int BPMval = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();
  SIM800L.write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("SIM800L set destination number.");
  SIM800L.write("AT+CMGS=\"0123456789\"\r");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Sending text message...");
  SIM800L.write("Your heart rate are: ");
  SIM800L.write(BPMval);
  SIM800L.write(" BPM");
  SIM800L.write("\r");
  Serial.println("Your heart rate are: ");
  Serial.print(BPMval);
  Serial.println(" BPM");
  SIM800L.write((char)26);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("SMS sent.");
}

void text_message_2(){
  int BPMval = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();
  SIM800L.write("AT+CMGF=1\r");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("SIM800L set destination number.");
  SIM800L.write("AT+CMGS=\"0123456789\"\r");
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("Sending text message...");
  SIM800L.write("Warning! Your heart rate are: ");
  SIM800L.write(BPMval);
  SIM800L.write(" BPM");
  SIM800L.write("\r");
  Serial.println("Warning! Your heart rate are: ");
  Serial.print(BPMval);
  Serial.println(" BPM");
  SIM800L.write((char)26);
  delay(100);
  Serial.println("SMS sent.");
}

void loop(){
  //int BPMval = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute();
  static enum {OPTION_ONE, OPTION_TWO, OPTION_THREE} condition;
  while (x == 0){
    mybutton.read();
    switch (condition){
      case OPTION_ONE:
      led_for_ages_range_1();
      range_1_indicator();
      if (mybutton.wasReleased()){      
        condition = OPTION_TWO;
      }
      break;

      case OPTION_TWO:
      led_for_ages_range_2();
      range_2_indicator();
      if (mybutton.wasReleased()){      
        condition = OPTION_THREE;
      }
      break;

      case OPTION_THREE:
      led_for_ages_range_3();
      range_3_indicator();
      if (mybutton.wasReleased()){      
        condition = OPTION_ONE;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: examine you code carefully ... for example, you get no warning at 90bpm  (there are more like that)

Comment: That just an example value, i intend to use `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: do you have a test sketch or some example sketch for the pulse sensor? does it work? or it doesn't work only in a sketch with SIM800 and SoftwareSerial

Comment: @Juraj. Yes i have, and it works perfectly when i use example sketch from the PulseSensorPlayground library. Also it works with SIM800L and SoftwareSerial when it still in simple sketch, i'm not adding switch-case for switching for the ages range and LED status at that time, because i don't insert any ages options program. Is it because of my faulty switch-case logic? But that switch-case logic also works for changing LED status and 3 different range values when i use potentiometer for changing the analog input value that change the LED indicator. And the text message also works.

Comment: add this to question

Comment: I'm getting fluctuations in BPM (it varies from 40 to 250). Most of the times, its in the 200s. Sometimes, it comes down to 90 or 80. [pulse sensor](http://bigbelectronics.in/product.php?product=pulse-heart-rate-sensor-module-arduino-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot `pulseSensor.begin()` and you don't use `pulseSensor.sawNewSample()`. See the examples of the library.

The library uses interrupts to measure the pulse. (It takes time, which would otherwise block the loop execution). The `begin()` function starts this interrupts.

The value measured by interrupts is accessible with `getBeatsPerMinute()` and `sawNewSample()` function indicates that new value is available.

The library can work without interrupts (PulseSensor_BPM_Alternative.ino), but even then the `begin()` function initializes the library and `sawNewSample()` is then the function which **reads** the sensor.

Comment: Did you see that in "Getting BPM_to_Monitor" sample sketch? In that sketch `pulseSensor.begin()` run only once and it's to print text inside `Serial.println`. Why i need to use `pulseSensor.sawNewSample()`? Its only return true or false because it's a boolean.

Comment: without `begin` the library doesn't read the sensor. getBeatsPerMinute is only a getter which reads a variable in library.

Comment: I enhanced the answer.

Comment: Oh i see.  I will try that.

Comment: I added `pulseSensor.begin()` and it works. But it getting error when i write `pulseSensor.sawNewSample()`, some of the LEDs always fast blinking and not in full brightness. But overall it works by adding `pulseSensor.begin()`. Thanks